# How to output javascript variable to the console?

Tags: javascript

If I'm using the following code to make a calculation and assign it to a variable, how would I go about making that variable accessible anywhere on the html page? I thought that simply declaring it as `result from elsewhere on the page = (quantity * product).toFixed(2) ;`would then allow me to output it to the console using `console.log('result from elsewhere on the page is p * q ' + result);`
 but when I do that I get `result from elsewhere on the page is p * q [object HTMLSpanElement]` as the output

```
<script>
$('#quantity,#product').bind('change keyup', function () {
  var product = $('#product').val(),
      quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10),
      result = (quantity * product).toFixed(2);
  $('#result').text(result);
  console.log('Testing console');
  console.log('result is p * q ' + result);
  console.log('quantity is ' + quantity);
});

</script>
```

note: the first output `console.log('result is p * q ' + result);`
 works fine and outputs `result is p * q 98.00` it's only when I try it from outside of the   that I get the `result from elsewhere on the page is p * q [object HTMLSpanElement]` returned.

thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Let's see the code you're using elsewhere on the page as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.result` or `window["result"]` notations.

EDIT: I assumed that u haven't changed the `result` somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable declaration for `result` there.

```
var ...., result = (quantity * product).toFixed(2);
```

When you declare a variable like that it gets declared *in the scope of the current function* (or the global scope if performing it outside of all functions).

Instead, declare it in the outside scope and just use it:

```
var result;
$('#quantity,#product').bind('change keyup', function () {
  var product = $('#product').val(),
      quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);

  result = (quantity * product).toFixed(2);
  $('#result').text(result);
  console.log('Testing console');
  console.log('result is p * q ' + result);
  console.log('quantity is ' + quantity);
});
//result is now available here, 
// (but equal to undefined until someone will trigger the event)
```

Note that since you get "result from elsewhere on the page is p * q [object HTMLSpanElement]" chances are you *already have* a `result` variable in that scope. Make sure you don't or give it another name.